# asp.net Login Website from database

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication

I have a website with a login, from a database.

This is my code :

```
        protected void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Movie;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string cmdStr = "select count(*) from Users";

            cmdStr += "where Username='" + UsernameSignIn.Text + "'";
            cmdStr+= "AND Password='"+PasswordSignIn.Text+"'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);

            int i = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (i == 0)
            {
                ErrorSignIn.Text = "Sorry, Wrong Username or Password";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("HomeAfter.aspx");
            }
        }
```

for some reason, I run into an error :

> Incorrect syntax near '-'

.
(for this line : `int i = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` )

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no spacing. Your query looks like this:

select count(*) from Userswhere Username='...'AND Password='...'

Add spaces, like so:

```
string cmdStr = "select count(*) from Users";
cmdStr += " where Username='" + UsernameSignIn.Text + "'";
cmdStr+= " AND Password='"+PasswordSignIn.Text+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that this is particularly crude as a form of authentication (you really ought to consider using the built-in ASP.NET Membership provider(s)) you should at a minimum be using parameterized SQL queries, rather than concatenating plain text to create your SQL statement. Also, I notice that your "login" arrangement simply does a response.redirect to the HomeAfter.aspx page without storing anything to be re-used that will indicate the user has already successfully logged in, such as a cookie or a sesssion variable.

Is there any particular reason for all this, or is it because you're just starting out and you need to study up a bit?